# adding an image inside navigation drawer - android

Tags: java, android

I want to add an image with a link inside a navigation drawer,

> is it possible to add an image inside navigation drawer ?
>
> I added coding like this but it is showing below error please check

```
  ImageView imageView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageView6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                specialOffers = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.specialOffers);
                specialOffers.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                specialOffers.loadUrl("http://www.fbcdubai.com/membership/offres-privileges/");
            }
            });


    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a listView inside the drawer navigation then create a custom item with image view finally attach it to a custom adapter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/***"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/***"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include layout="@layout/****"
                android:id="@+id/nav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/***"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

cust item

    enter code here
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/****"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/****"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i use your code and edited its working image is can you please explain how to make click event to this image.. ? sorry for asking here I'm unable to ask new questions because I have got minus ratings in this question  @Syrine BOUSLIMI

Answer (score 2):

open `nav_header_layout_name.xml`  and add image view say (ProfileImage)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_head"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

to access this image view from the java class:
- `NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_id);`
- `View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);`
- `ImageView ProfileImage = (ImageViwe) hView.findViewById(R.id.home_profile_image);`

Comment: thanks for answer.but i used above answer and got image. can you pleas tell me  how to make click event to that image? I'm unable to ask new questions bcoz this question has got minus rankings .. if you can pleas help

Comment: ProfileImage .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //YOUR_ACTION
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can do this by setting a listener to your image inside the getView method of the adapter

```
discu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

//put here your code

});

Comment: hi thnks i added your code but it is showing an error please check its in question i edited please check if you can    @Syrine BOUSLIMI